# Which pattern to use in order to execute new code by just adding new subclasses of a base class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to figure out a pattern to avoid code duplication in a situation similar to the one bellow:

```
std::list<int> error_list;
void validate()
{
    if( validate_0001() == false )
    { error_list.push_back(1); }

    if( validate_0002() == false )
    { error_list.push_back(2); }

    ...
}
```

The method 'validate' is public in a class responsible for performing different actions, in the example validations, each one with an unique id. I want to be able to add a new action by just extending a base class, without the need to create a new method and add its call and its error handling inside the validate method.

Comment: If I correctly understood your question: 1. Add the validate_xxx functions/error codes pairs in a vector. 2. In validate() call each function in vector and return the associated code if it fails.

Comment: Have you considered a `vector` of lambda expressions, with each expression being a test [or something similar](https://ideone.com/s9uWKG)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting you use validating decorators (Here is a Java example)

```html
    abstract class Validation {
        final List<Integer> list;

        Validation(List<Integer> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public abstract int error();
    }

    class FirstValidation extends Validation {

        public FirstValidation(List<Integer> list) {
            super(list);
        }

        @Override
        public int error() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't really extend a single function from a base class without extending the whole class.
One thing you can do is make the validation methods in a separate class and extend it by the two other classes. Another thing you can do is make the validations as an abstract class and implement it as you please in the child classes,the disadvantage of this approach is that you would have to provide the implementation in each of the child classes.